# Arquillian - Weld SE - getting NullPointerException

Tags: cdi, jboss-weld, jboss-arquillian

I am new to Arquillian and want to get some basic testing working (inject a bean and assert it does something).

Exception:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.walterjwhite.test.TestCase
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.231 sec <<< FAILURE!
test(com.walterjwhite.test.TestCase)  Time elapsed: 0.02 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inject members
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.injectClass(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:113)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.enrich(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:61)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.enricher.ClientTestEnricher.enrich(ClientTestEnricher.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:98)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createBeforeContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:126)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:106)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.before(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:210)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:303)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$300(Arquillian.java:45)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:228)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:173)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:303)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$300(Arquillian.java:45)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:187)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.getBeanManager(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:51)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.injectClass(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:100)
    ... 71 more
```

TestCase class

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestCase
{
    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment()
    {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class).addClasses(TestEntity.class, Implementation.class)
                                         .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));
    }

    @Inject
    Implementation implementation;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception
    {
        final TestEntity testEntity = implementation.create();

        Assert.assertNotNull(testEntity);
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get a NullPointerException, the bean manager is null.  It looks like I am missing a step, but from the examples, it looks like this is all I should need.

Any ideas?

Walter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like are trying to use the latest snapshot. Currently the Arquillian repository is being restructured, so unless you have a specific reason for tracking HEAD, I recommend using Alpha5.

You can see working CDI examples in the Arquillian showcase. http://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-showcase

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with arquillian 1.0.4.Final. Getting "java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inject members" plus stacktrace. This on tests running since a year. The JUnit tests worked if calling the test classes one by one, but failed if calling all test either by doing a Junit test of the whole module, or doing a maven site test of the whole project. No matter to solve the problem, but resetting the arquillian version back to 1.0.3.Final!